# Create Hybrid application using HTML5 and javascript

Tags: windows, html, hybrid

I have to developed applications through Visual studio which will run on windows mobile, windows Tablet as well as windows computer(desktop computer and laptop). I am planning to develop hybrid applications using HTML5/JavaScript/jQuery.

Please suggest, What type of software will required for developing this type of application.

Is there a place where I can get information on the different frameworks and how hybrid architecture should be used?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you:

Multi-Device Hybrid App extension for Visual Studio.

or

Intel XDK

Also Telerik AppBuilder which is an online (paid) tool